# Doctrine Relation One-To-Many don't show all results in Synfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-many

I'm on Symfony 2.8.15 and I have a problem with a doctrine relation One-To-Many.
I have an entity InvitesGroupe and an entity Reservations. InvitesGroupe can have One or Many Reservations. So there is a `hasReservations()` method in.

It works, my application is in production for month. But recently I see a huge result : Not all possibilities are shown. I have an InviteGroupe which have 43 Reservations in the database, all the same format apart the date but only 42 are shown.

If a try the query from the profiler, I have the 43 reservations.

I try many debug, but I don't know what append.

the (owning) InvitesGroupe entities :

```
<?php

namespace Ipb\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * InvitesGroupe
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="invites_groupe", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="FK_invites_groupe_id_service", columns={"id_service"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ipb\AppBundle\EntityRepository\InvitesGroupeRepository")
 */
class InvitesGroupe
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_invite", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idInvite;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom_reservation", type="string", length=30, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max = 30)
     *
     */
    private $nomReservation;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="commentaire", type="text", length=65535, precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     */
    private $commentaire;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="repas", type="boolean", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $repas = 1;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="repas_offert", type="boolean", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $repasOffert = false;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="place_table", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     */
    private $placeTable;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="invite_visible", type="boolean", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $inviteVisible = true;

    /**
     * @var \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Users
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id_user", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $idUser;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dessert", type="boolean", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $dessert = false;

     /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="wine", type="boolean", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $wine = false;

     /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="coffee", type="boolean", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     */
    private $coffee = false;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="invite_temporaire", type="boolean", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $inviteTemporaire;

    /**
     * @var \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Services
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Services")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_service", referencedColumnName="id_service", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $idService;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Reservations", mappedBy="invitesGroupe", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     */
    private $reservations;



    /**
     * Get idInvite
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIdInvite()
    {
        return $this->idInvite;
    }

    /**
     * Set nombre
     *
     * @param integer $nombre
     * @return InvitesGroupe
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nombre
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    /**
     * Set nomReservation
     *
     * @param string $nomReservation
     * @return InvitesGroupe
     */
    public function setNomReservation($nomReservation)
    {
        $this->nomReservation = $nomReservation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nomReservation
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNomReservation()
    {
        return $this->nomReservation;
    }

    /**
     * Set commentaire
     *
     * @param string $commentaire
     * @return InvitesGroupe
     */
    public function setCommentaire($commentaire)
    {
        $this->commentaire = $commentaire;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get commentaire
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCommentaire()
    {
        return $this->commentaire;
    }

    /**
     * Set repas
     *
     * @param boolean $repas
     * @return InvitesGroupe
     */
    public function setRepas($repas)
    {
        $this->repas = $repas;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get repas
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getRepas()
    {
        return $this->repas;
    }

    /**
     * Set repasOffert
     *
     * @param boolean $repasOffert
     * @return InvitesGroupe
     */
    public function setRepasOffert($repasOffert)
    {
        $this->repasOffert = $repasOffert;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get repasOffert
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getRepasOffert()
    {
        return $this->repasOffert;
    }

    /**
     * Set placeTable
     *
     * @param integer $placeTable
     * @return InvitesGroupe
     */
    public function setPlaceTable($placeTable)
    {
        $this->placeTable = $placeTable;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get placeTable
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getPlaceTable()
    {
        return $this->placeTable;
    }

    /**
     * Set inviteVisible
     *
     * @param boolean $inviteVisible
     * @return InvitesGroupe
     */
    public function setInviteVisible($inviteVisible)
    {
        $this->inviteVisible = $inviteVisible;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get inviteVisible
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getInviteVisible()
    {
        return $this->inviteVisible;
    }

    /**
     * Set dessert
     *
     * @param boolean $dessert
     * @return InvitesGroupe
     */
    public function setDessert($dessert)
    {
        $this->dessert = $dessert;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dessert
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getDessert()
    {
        return $this->dessert;
    }

    /**
     * Set idService
     *
     * @param \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Services $idService
     * @return InvitesGroupe
     */
    public function setIdService(\Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Services $idService = null)
    {
        $this->idService = $idService;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idService
     *
     * @return \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Services 
     */
    public function getIdService()
    {
        return $this->idService;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->reservations = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add reservations
     *
     * @param \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Reservations $reservations
     * @return Reservations
     */
    public function addReservation(\Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Reservations $reservations)
    {
        $this->reservations[] = $reservations;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove reservations
     *
     * @param \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Reservations $reservations
     */
    public function removeReservation(\Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Reservations $reservations)
    {
        $this->reservations->removeElement($reservations);
    }

    /**
     * Get reservations
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getReservations()
    {
        return $this->reservations;
    }

    /**
     * Set inviteTemporaire
     *
     * @param boolean $inviteTemporaire
     *
     * @return InvitesGroupe
     */
    public function setInviteTemporaire($inviteTemporaire)
    {
        $this->inviteTemporaire = $inviteTemporaire;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get inviteTemporaire
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getInviteTemporaire()
    {
        return $this->inviteTemporaire;
    }

    /**
     * Set wine
     *
     * @param boolean $wine
     *
     * @return InvitesGroupe
     */
    public function setWine($wine)
    {
        $this->wine = $wine;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get wine
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getWine()
    {
        return $this->wine;
    }

    /**
     * Set coffee
     *
     * @param boolean $coffee
     *
     * @return InvitesGroupe
     */
    public function setCoffee($coffee)
    {
        $this->coffee = $coffee;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get coffee
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getCoffee()
    {
        return $this->coffee;
    }

    /**
     * Set idUser
     *
     * @param \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Users $idUser
     *
     * @return InvitesGroupe
     */
    public function setIdUser(\Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Users $idUser = null)
    {
        $this->idUser = $idUser;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idUser
     *
     * @return \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Users
     */
    public function getIdUser()
    {
        return $this->idUser;
    }
}
```

and the Reservations entity :

```
<?php

namespace Ipb\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Reservations
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="reservations", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="FK_reservations_id_invite", columns={"id_invite"}), @ORM\Index(name="FK_reservations_id_service", columns={"id_service"}), @ORM\Index(name="FK_reservations_id_restaurant", columns={"id_restaurant"}), @ORM\Index(name="FK_reservations_id_groupe_personnel", columns={"id_groupe_personnel"}), @ORM\Index(name="FK_reservations_id_classe", columns={"id_classe"}), @ORM\Index(name="FK_reservations_id_groupe", columns={"id_groupe"}), @ORM\Index(name="key_date_resa", columns={"date"})})
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ipb\AppBundle\EntityRepository\ReservationsRepository")
 */
class Reservations
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_reservation", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=false, unique=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idReservation;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nb_place", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $nbPlace;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cout_total", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $coutTotal;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="repas_compris", type="boolean", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $repasCompris;

    /**
     * @var \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\GroupesPersonnels
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\GroupesPersonnels")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_groupe_personnel", referencedColumnName="id_groupe_personnel", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $idGroupePersonnel;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="incertain", type="integer", precision=0, scale=0, nullable=true, unique=false)
     */
    private $incertain;

    /**
     * @var \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Classes
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Classes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_classe", referencedColumnName="id_classe", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $idClasse;

    /**
     * @var \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Groupes
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Groupes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_groupe", referencedColumnName="id_groupe", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $idGroupe;

    /**
     * @var \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\InvitesGroupe
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\InvitesGroupe")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_invite", referencedColumnName="id_invite", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $idInvite;

    /**
     * @var \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Restaurants
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Restaurants")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_restaurant", referencedColumnName="id_restaurant", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $idRestaurant;

    /**
     * @var \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Services
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Services")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_service", referencedColumnName="id_service", nullable=true)
     * })
     */
    private $idService;

     /**
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\InvitesGroupe", inversedBy="reservations", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_invite", referencedColumnName="id_invite", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $invitesGroupe;



    /**
     * Get idReservation
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIdReservation()
    {
        return $this->idReservation;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     * @return Reservations
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set nbPlace
     *
     * @param integer $nbPlace
     * @return Reservations
     */
    public function setNbPlace($nbPlace)
    {
        $this->nbPlace = $nbPlace;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nbPlace
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getNbPlace()
    {
        return $this->nbPlace;
    }

    /**
     * Set coutTotal
     *
     * @param float $coutTotal
     * @return Reservations
     */
    public function setCoutTotal($coutTotal)
    {
        $this->coutTotal = $coutTotal;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get coutTotal
     *
     * @return float 
     */
    public function getCoutTotal()
    {
        return $this->coutTotal;
    }

    /**
     * Set repasCompris
     *
     * @param boolean $repasCompris
     * @return Reservations
     */
    public function setRepasCompris($repasCompris)
    {
        $this->repasCompris = $repasCompris;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get repasCompris
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getRepasCompris()
    {
        return $this->repasCompris;
    }

    /**
     * Set idGroupePersonnel
     *
     * @param integer $idGroupePersonnel
     * @return Reservations
     */
    public function setIdGroupePersonnel($idGroupePersonnel)
    {
        $this->idGroupePersonnel = $idGroupePersonnel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idGroupePersonnel
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIdGroupePersonnel()
    {
        return $this->idGroupePersonnel;
    }

    /**
     * Set incertain
     *
     * @param integer $incertain
     * @return Reservations
     */
    public function setIncertain($incertain)
    {
        $this->incertain = $incertain;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get incertain
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getIncertain()
    {
        return $this->incertain;
    }

    /**
     * Set idClasse
     *
     * @param \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Classes $idClasse
     * @return Reservations
     */
    public function setIdClasse(\Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Classes $idClasse = null)
    {
        $this->idClasse = $idClasse;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idClasse
     *
     * @return \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Classes 
     */
    public function getIdClasse()
    {
        return $this->idClasse;
    }

    /**
     * Set idGroupe
     *
     * @param \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Groupes $idGroupe
     * @return Reservations
     */
    public function setIdGroupe(\Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Groupes $idGroupe = null)
    {
        $this->idGroupe = $idGroupe;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idGroupe
     *
     * @return \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Groupes 
     */
    public function getIdGroupe()
    {
        return $this->idGroupe;
    }

    /**
     * Set idInvite
     *
     * @param \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\InvitesGroupe $idInvite
     * @return Reservations
     */
    public function setIdInvite(\Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\InvitesGroupe $idInvite = null)
    {
        $this->idInvite = $idInvite;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idInvite
     *
     * @return \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\InvitesGroupe 
     */
    public function getIdInvite()
    {
        return $this->idInvite;
    }

    /**
     * Set idRestaurant
     *
     * @param \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Restaurants $idRestaurant
     * @return Reservations
     */
    public function setIdRestaurant(\Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Restaurants $idRestaurant = null)
    {
        $this->idRestaurant = $idRestaurant;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idRestaurant
     *
     * @return \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Restaurants 
     */
    public function getIdRestaurant()
    {
        return $this->idRestaurant;
    }

    /**
     * Set idService
     *
     * @param \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Services $idService
     * @return Reservations
     */
    public function setIdService(\Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Services $idService = null)
    {
        $this->idService = $idService;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idService
     *
     * @return \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\Services 
     */
    public function getIdService()
    {
        return $this->idService;
    }


    /**
     * Set invitesGroupe
     *
     * @param \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\InvitesGroupe $invitesGroupe
     * @return Reservations
     */
    public function setInvitesGroupes(\Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\InvitesGroupe $invitesGroupe = null)
    {
        $this->invitesGroupe = $invitesGroupe;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get invitesGroupes
     *
     * @return \Ipb\AppBundle\Entity\InvitesGroupes
     */
    public function getInvitesGroupe()
    {
        return $this->invitesGroupe;
    }
}
```

the controller :

```
/**
     * Lists all InvitesGroupe entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="invitesgroupe_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $day = $request->get('day');
        $resto = $request->get('resto');

        $user = !$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_SUPERVISEUR') ? "AND ig.idUser = '".$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getIdUser()."'" : "";

        if($day){
            $day = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $day);
            $dql   = "SELECT ig FROM IpbAppBundle:InvitesGroupe ig 
                    LEFT JOIN IpbAppBundle:Reservations r WITH r.idInvite = ig.idInvite
                    WHERE ig.inviteVisible = 1
                    AND ig.inviteTemporaire IS NULL
                    AND r.date = '".$day->format('Y-m-d')."'
                    ".$user."
                    ORDER BY ig.idInvite DESC";
        }else if($resto && $day){
            $day = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $day);
            $dql   = "SELECT ig FROM IpbAppBundle:InvitesGroupe ig 
                    LEFT JOIN IpbAppBundle:Reservations r WITH r.idInvite = ig.idInvite
                    WHERE ig.inviteVisible = 1 AND ig.inviteTemporaire IS NULL
                    AND r.idRestaurant = ".$resto."
                    AND r.date = '".$day->format('Y-m-d')."'
                    ".$user."
                    ORDER BY ig.idInvite DESC";

        }else{
            $dql   = "SELECT ig FROM IpbAppBundle:InvitesGroupe ig
                    LEFT JOIN IpbAppBundle:Reservations r WITH r.idInvite = ig.idInvite
                    WHERE ig.inviteVisible = 1 AND ig.inviteTemporaire IS NULL
                    AND r.date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
                    ".$user."
                    ORDER BY ig.idInvite DESC";
        }

        $query = $em->createQuery($dql);


        $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $query, /* query NOT result */
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
            10/*limit per page*/
        );

        $deleteForms = array();

        if(null !== $request->get('print')){
            return $pagination;
        }

        foreach ($pagination as $page) {
            $deleteForms[$page->getIdInvite()] = $this->createDeleteForm($page)->createView();
        }

        if($day){
            $restoTest = array();
            $restos = array();
            foreach ($pagination as $invite) {
                if(!in_array($invite->getIdService()->getIdRestaurant()->getIdRestaurant(), $restoTest)){
                    $obj = new \stdClass();
                    $obj->id = $invite->getIdService()->getIdRestaurant()->getIdRestaurant();
                    $obj->nom = $invite->getIdService()->getIdRestaurant()->getNomRestaurant();
                    $restos[] = $obj;
                    $restoTest[] = $invite->getIdService()->getIdRestaurant()->getIdRestaurant();

                }
            }
        }



        return $this->render('invitesgroupe/index.html.twig', array(
            'invitesGroupes' =>  $pagination, 
            'delete_forms' => $deleteForms,
            'day'  => $day ? $day : null,
            'restos' => isset($restos) ? json_encode($restos) : null
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code used, to extract the result from the database

Comment: Did you validate the data models?

Comment: Can you share the query are you using for getting all reservations?

Comment: You have to dig into the profiler to find the SQL query that is running and debug that.

Comment: I copy-paste the sql in a console and all works fine : `code 
SELECT t0.id_reservation AS id_reservation_1, t0.date AS date_2, t0.nb_place AS nb_place_3, t0.cout_total AS cout_total_4, t0.repas_compris AS repas_compris_5, t0.incertain AS incertain_6, t0.id_groupe_personnel AS id_groupe_personnel_7, t0.id_classe AS id_classe_8, t0.id_groupe AS id_groupe_9, t0.id_invite AS id_invite_10, t0.id_restaurant AS id_restaurant_11, t0.id_service AS id_service_12, t0.id_invite AS id_invite_13 FROM reservations t0 WHERE t0.id_invite = 1923 `

Comment: But still one date is missing in symfony